# How to compare two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I have data in excel like below

```
columnA                         columnB     columnC 
Saidabad S.O (Hyderabad)        500059      500059
Samskruthi S.O                  500088      
Sanath Nagar Colony S.O         500018      500018
```

if columnB and columnC are equal then i want the following result
then I have output like

```
columnA                         columnB     columnC   columnD 
Saidabad S.O (Hyderabad)        500059      500059    Saidabad S.O (Hyderabad)
Sanath Nagar Colony S.O         500018      500018    Sanath Nagar Colony S.O
```

Is it possible to do this in excel. If it is possible then please give me formula for my query

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's very unclear what you want... do you mean that if columnB and columnC are equal... then columnD=columnA? And otherwise that it should not be shown?

Comment: Is it possible to what exactly?

Comment: sorry sorry .. if columnB and columnC are equal then i want that result

Comment: question is update pls find that

Answer (score 0):

put `=IF(B2=C2,A2,"-")` in D2. Then drag it down as far as needed. Then select the `AUTO FILTER` option and filter out the "-" from columnD.